# TypeScript: is there a way to programatically construct an interface using an enum

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have an `enum` defined as this

```
enum EventType {
  JOB,
  JOB_EXECUTION,
  JOB_GROUP
}
```

And I need to create an interface like this

```
interface EventConfigurations {
  JOB: {
    Enabled?: boolean;
  };

  JOB_EXECUTION: {
    Enabled?: boolean;
  };

  JOB_GROUP: {
    Enabled?: boolean;
  };
}
```

Given there is a one to one mapping existing between them, I wonder if there is a way to generate this `interface` based on the `enum`? Currently I just hardcoded it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create it as a type (not an interface) like this:

```
type EventConfigurations = Record<keyof typeof EventType, { Enabled?: boolean }>
```

Explanation:

- Using `typeof` on an `enum` gives a type with each of its string members as keys and numbers as values.
- Using `keyof` on that type gives a union type containing each of those keys.
- `Record<K, V>` is a mapping from type `K` to type `V`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN4FgBQURUAUgPIBCANAcaZQPowAaMAwgKrICSZAcjULFyFBgHEASmQ4AFQQF8CBRBizwkbAPYgAZgEsA5mABOAQ0R7tAZygBeKBOABjTcYAmAHgDWwVJp1QKpj+sAggKKpUOLAgpgBGADbAbgD8AFxQcZqaSaYgUPIAfEr4LiBWiFDAYYhauoYm5pblGerhdfpGZhbWdji0wpQZ2PKCA0QiTKycPPzD43Qx8UluGYjGYMCCdKMldJOS0jLzQotLickZOqYJVlsLu-iK+EA)